# BCM4331 wireless causes graphics corruption on MacBook Pro 10,2

Tags: wireless, 14.04, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro 10,2 and just installed 14.04. Everything seems okay except when I enable the wireless driver for the BCM4331 I get intermittent graphics corruption. It looks like the screen loses horizontal sync. If I disable the driver, the graphics looks great. Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Please post a photo of the situation

Comment: Here's a video of the issue. http://youtu.be/PlM3Nyi0Hc0.

Comment: For future reference. I have a similar problem with the 12,1 and bcm5974. It helped to turn the wifi bandwidth down to 20MHz (from 40) at the router.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have it on 10,2 running 22.4.1 LTS. Sitting somewhere with less Wi-Fi interference helps, but otherwise the only solution is to switch Wi-Fi off which is obviously not ideal. Doesn't happen with Wi-Fi off!

Answer (score 0):

This is not a straight forward answer, but I'll list the options you have.

First you must identify whether this is a hardware fault or a software fault. To do that, you need to install a screen recorder like Kazaam from Ubuntu software center and see whether you can capture this screen flickering to a video file.  If the recorded video has the flickering, then this is a software related issue.

Software related issues occur mostly because of drivers.

First search `additional drivers` in Ubuntu dash and see whether you have proprietary drivers available to install.

[image]

You can try to re install the BCM4331 driver. To do so open your terminal and execute the command below:

> sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer