# BCM4331 causes graphics to fail on MacBook Pro 10,1

Tags: wireless, drivers, macbook-pro

I just installed a fresh Ubuntu 14.04 TLS installation on my Mac using [rEFInd](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) since my last installation did not work. When I install Ubuntu, the wireless does not work. But installing the [bcm43xx drivers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access) causes my screen to constant flicker.

I think I really have the wrong drivers. This is the result after executing lspci:

```
ricardo@ubuntu:~$ lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16a3] (rev10)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:16b4]
03:00.1 SD Host controller [0805]: Broadcom Corporation BCM57765/57785 SDXC/MMC Card Reader [14e4:16bc] (rev 10) (prog-if 01)
        Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:96bc]
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n [14e4:4331] (rev 02)
```

Could somebody advice me in my quest to get my wireless working without my screen to flicker?

**EDIT:** I did some things since my post. A quick coverage:

- I followed the [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_No_Internet_access) earlier in my post resulting in a working wireless but with flickering screen.

Then I did

- Opening Additional Drivers and installed the latest (NVIDIA GK107M) [650M Mac Edition]
- Also installed the suggested Broadcom drivers.

It seem to work now, but sometimes I get a panic at boot resulting in rebooting twice before I can re-use Ubuntu. Small issue left apart from the panics: I only can set the resolution 2880 x 1800. Anyway to get smaller resolutions?

Comment: Found the same issue here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/474475/bcm4331-wireless-causes-graphics-corruption-on-macbook-pro-10-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt the wireless driver is causing your video issue but all you have to do is remove the driver you installed then reboot and install it this way to find out.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

reboot.

Comment: I removed the nvidia drivers by doing a apt-get remove nvidia*. Then I added the vga tag to my boot options and that seem to work for now. Thank you for the alternative solution.

Comment: The wireless (driver) [indeed causes this issue](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Fix-Flickering-Display-on-MacBook-Pro-Retina-427598.shtml). I have same problem here under Debian Jessie, using Nouveau. The moment I disable the wifi, the screen is 100%. I'm not sure about changing wifi channels as mentioned there, but this is definitely a real issue with these devices.